# jQuery. How do I grab text of the parent element in the following element hierarchy?

Tags: jquery, html

Given the following element hierarchy:

[image]

Using jQuery, how do I grab the text **abc** from the parent `div` element with id **up_tag_div**?

If I simple use `$('#up_tag_div').text()` the resultant text is **abcdef**. Not what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this

```
$("#up_tag_div").clone().children()
    .remove().end().text();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the text content always precedes any children, you can do this:

```
$('#up_tag_div').contents()[0].textContent
```

```js
console.log($('#up_tag_div').contents()[0].textContent);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="up_tag_div">
  "abc"
  <div>def</div>
  <div>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the text *doesn't* necessarily precede any children:

```
$('#up_tag_div')
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return !this.tagName  //skip elements
  })
  .text()  
  .trim()
```

```js
console.log($('#up_tag_div').contents().filter(function() {return !this.tagName}).text().trim());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="up_tag_div">
  <div>def</div>
  "abc"
  <div>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```